# Cygwin Error while runnin build_native.sh

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cygwin

I get the error

$ ./build_native.sh
NDK_ROOT = D:\android-ndk-r8d
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /cygdrive/d/Cocos2D/cocos2d-2.1beta3-x-2.1.0/two_alian/proj.android/../..
APP_ROOT = /cygdrive/d/Cocos2D/cocos2d-2.1beta3-x-2.1.0/two_alian/proj.android/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /cygdrive/d/Cocos2D/cocos2d-2.1beta3-x-2.1.0/two_alian/proj.android
Using prebuilt externals
make: Entering directory `/cygdrive/d/Cocos2D/cocos2d-2.1beta3-x-2.1.0/two_alian/proj.android'
Compile++ thumb  : game_shared <= HelloWorldScene.cpp
jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp: In member function 'void HelloWorld::spriteMoveFinished(cocos2d::CCNode*)':
jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:130:2: error: 'CCsprite' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:130:12: error: 'sprite' was not declared in this scope
/cygdrive/d/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/build-binary.mk:269: recipe for target`obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/**/**/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/**/**/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/d/Cocos2D/cocos2d-2.1beta3-x-2.1.0/two_alian/proj.android'

But all in the scope

Answer (score 0):

From reading this it appears that inside your `HelloWorldScene.cpp` you have typo.

`CCsprite` should be `CCSprite`.

This is just one error, there may be many more, it is impossible to tell from what you have posted.